# How to upload laravel projects to domain

Tags: php, laravel-5

I tried to upload my project using GoDaddy domain and when the uploading is done.
I was expecting that my site or website is ready for viewing but when I visit it, it shows that it has a missing file which is the "index.php".
Even in the project that runs in my localhost doesn't have that file but it runs well.
Here is a link to my project that has been upload to my domain.
e-trendzone.php

Comment: The `index.php` file is inside `/public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel default project doesn't have index file in laravel (app) directory list. So, you can add the index file to redirect that to your public folder.

This is example.

```
<!html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = "http://your-url/public"
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, Thank You Sir I'll try this one